# How do I know which view is throwing the error?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a piece of code that used to work just fine.
And then suddenly it started throwing this error:

```
  07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:946)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:555)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:913)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2824)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at com.werbuy.werbuy.activities.PurchaseActivity.onLanguageChanged(PurchaseActivity.java:677)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at com.werbuy.werbuy.fragments.SettingsFragment$7.onItemClick(SettingsFragment.java:405)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at com.quickaction.QuickAction$2.onItemClick(QuickAction.java:184)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-29 14:20:45.160: E/crash(28862):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This falls when i call

```
fragmentAdapter.notifiyDataSetChanged(); //<this call used to work just fine
```

All my fragment's `onCreateView` looks like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, null);
}
```

How do i know which view is causing the problem ?

EDIT the pager adapter

```
public class PurchaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    @Inject
    public PurchaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void setFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments == null ? 0 : fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }


    public boolean setFragment(Fragment fragment, int position, boolean update) {
        if(fragment == null) {

            return false;
        }

        fragments.set(position, fragment);
        if(update) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean removeFragmentAtIndex(int position, boolean update) {
        if (getCount()<position -1) {
            return false;
        }
        fragments.remove(position);
        if(update) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, null) to inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, null,false);

Comment: Are you calling addView() somewhere in your code?

Comment: You might be trying to add a fragment to a container before removing the existing fragment on the container.

Comment: @joao2fast4u no i am not calling addView anywhere in my code at all

Comment: Could you show your fragmentAdapter code, please?

Comment: What are you doing in onLanguageChanged()? Your crash is there.

Comment: fragmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is inside onLanguagechanged the crash is that line, if i remove it, no crash, but no update either

Answer (score 0):

The problem was one particular fragment
SupportMapFragment by google maps, which was one of my viewpager fragments.
Unfortunately,it was embedded in the xml I was loading. Once i started loading it dynamically, the problem went away